# How do you translate the world "layer" in Japanese?

Tags: translation, word-choice, word-requests, english-to-japanese, questions

Layer as in the ones used in digital art software like Adobe Photoshop, Clip Studio Paint, Manga Studio, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [レイヤー](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A4%E3%83%BC+%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E5%8A%A0%E5%B7%A5).

It's also what they use in Adobe's official [Photoshop tutorials](https://helpx.adobe.com/jp/search.html?q=%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A4%E3%83%BC).